# Import face_recognition or dlib crashes kernel in python

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib

I have a Macbook Air M1, and I installed the face_recognition package, and the dlib package, in Anaconda.
I downloaded everything using conda forge, in a separate environment. Everything seemed to work fine, but when I try to "import face_recognition" or "import dlib" in python, I have this error:

Restarting kernel...
[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: 00eb64226e2811ebb1561e00e20c3c85

This is the first time I see this error, I spent countless hours to find the same error on stackoverflow, but I did not find anything...

Thanks a lot for your help!